# Image Cropping Issues in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, image-processing

Everyone.

I have recently developed a newspaper website in WordPress.

In this I have 8 different sizes for same image.

For this I wrote following the code in function.php

```
    add_image_size( 'slider-side-thumb', 110, 85, true );
    add_image_size( 'gallery-thumb', 710, 280, true );
    add_image_size( 'slider-thumb', 450, 267, true );
    add_image_size( 'box-thumb', 340, 202, true );
    add_image_size( 'slide-thumb', 180, 250, true );

    add_image_size( 'single-thumb', 400, 240, true );
    add_image_size( 'inner-thumb', 180, 101, true );
    add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 830, 542, true );
```

It's working for all images. But the cropping of the images is not perfect.

How can I resolve this?

Or please suggest the best way to replace these 8 images with one image if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem..
By giving Cropping Parameter to false.

Eg:
 `add_image_size( 'single-thumb', 400, 240, false )`;